# Is it possible to dynamically set fields on subforms

Tags: form, xml, subform

If I have a subform with the following xml structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form>
    <fieldset
        name="advkontentuser"
    >
        <fieldset name="akuser" label="ADVKONTENT_USER_EDIT_FORM">
            <field
                name="akprofile"
                type="subform"
                label="AdvKontent User Profile"
                multiple="true"
                min="1"
                max="10"
                groupByFieldset="true"
                layout="joomla.form.field.subform.repeatable"
                >
                <form addfieldprefix="DeAnima\Component\AdvKontent\Administrator\Field">
                    <fieldset name="advkontent-user">
                        <fields name="details">
                            <field
                                name="userName"
                                type="text"
                                label="ADVKONTENT_NAME"
                                required="true"
                                labelclass="advkontentui-field-label"
                                maxlength="250"
                                class="advkontentui-field-value"
                            />
                            <field
                                name="gender"
                                type="radio"
                                default="n"
                                label="ADVKONTENT_GENDER"
                                labelClass="advkontentui-field-label"
                                class="advkontentui-field-value advkontentui-button-set"
                            >
                                <option value="n">ADVKONTENT_NOT_SPECIFIED</option>
                                <option value="m">ADVKONTENT_MALE</option>
                                <option value="f">ADVKONTENT_FEMALE</option>
                            </field>
                        </fields>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </field>
        </fieldset>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Is it possible to add fields dynamically to the fieldset "advkontent-user" as described in  the [Joomla document](https://docs.joomla.org/Advanced_form_guide#Dynamically_Setting_Fields)

I've tried the following code

```
$form->setFields($uepSubformFields, 'akprofile', 'false', 'advkontent-user');
```

However it's not adding anything. Are the values for the group and fieldset correct?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code in `../libraries/src/Form/Form.php` the `setFields()` function is a wrapper function to loop through `setField()` starting at line #781, both of which reject any bad xml syntax. Check first that your xml you are trying to introduce is valid xml.

I would also suggest your try adding just one new sub form element using `setField()` rather than `setFields()` until you can confirm something that works.

And I would then step through each line of code in `SetField()` with a Debugger to identify whether your Sub form is being found or not.

Looking in Github at `findFields()` and related functions that `setField()` relies on, there doesn't appear to be much code changed since 13-14 years ago, excluding clean ups, with only one mention I could find of a change relating to sub forms so I wouldn't be surprised if adding fields to sub-forms is not yet introduced at a code level in `FindFields()`.

This should show up in a debug when you see what is returned from `findFields()`